# Passing PID from ps command to netstat for port #

Tags: linux, awk, grep, xargs

I have a process that can have multiple instances.  ps shows the instance name, whereas netstat of course gives the name of the binary instead of the instance name.  My goal is to use something like

*ps -ef | grep Actimize_CDD | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'*

as input to grep on netstat, something like:

*netstat -anp | grep tcp | grep LISTEN | grep $resultFromPrevious | awk '{print substr($4, length($4)-3,length($0))}'*

I've been looking at xargs and tried a few command substitutions, but of course instead of grepping for the string it tries to execute grep on the input string.

Thoughts?  I'd like to stick with what I know (awk, piping, xargs) if possible, although I'm open to learning new things.

Comment: you can use backticks ( ` ) to get the result of a command... so if both your commands work for themselves that should do the trick. If not: more tinkering required.

Comment: you should state here (and focus on) your goal, not focus too much on the method you are attempting to use to reach it. If the goal is to list Ip infos about processes, try here: `lsof -Pn | grep "Actimize_CDD"` and grep further on the ip infos you seek

Answer (score 0):

I swear that I tried backtick, but der Bender is correct:

[root@puflopactmzaa01 External_File_System]# *netstat -anp | grep tcp | grep LISTEN | grep `ps -ef | grep Actimize_CDD | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'` | awk '{print substr($4, length($4)-3,length($0))}'*

yields the output:

2355
2356
2357
2358